# iPad Xcode 4.6.3 Landscape Orientation Only

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, orientation, landscape, xcode4.6.3

I have a problem about landscape orientation
I don't use storyboard.
In *.codeproj summary Supported interface orientation  "Landscape left and right selected"

In AppDelegate.m I used the method

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window

{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    else  /* iphone */
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

In ViewController.m I used the method

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

In viewcontroller.xib all the view (UIVIEW class) are:

Simulated Metrics
Landscape

In my viewController i have somes views (UIVIEW class) defined in viewController.m

The main view open correctly when I launch the application, but the other view open the first time in portrait mode, after when I rotate the IPAD the view change in landscape mode.

I would like that all the view open in landscape mode first time

I tried to change the method

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

but with this method the view never change and it stay in portrait mode

The main view appear always correctly in landscape mode, the problem is in other view.

Comment: Can Anyone help me about the problem described.

Comment: Can Anyone help me about the problem described?